# ComboBox that shows all removable devices

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, usb

I have a combobox (ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableDrives}").

The AvailableDrives property is defined like this:

```
 public List<DriveInfo> AvailableDrives
    {
        get
        {
            return DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).ToList();
        }
    }
```

It works OK, but i would like that if i plug in/out a USB device that the comboBox gets repopulated without having to close and reopen the window.

How can i achieve this?

thanx#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple method will be to put a timer on your form and query for the drives when its event fires. Then update combo box with new values.

Comment: thanx for the advice. I will try this aproach also.

Comment: well i kinda used this solution. Used System.Threading.Timer and handled the selected when it gets updated. It works.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good example of how to do this on codeproject: [Detecting USB Drive Removal in a C# Program](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx)

Comment: i belive this is the correct solution, yet i managed to do what i wanted using timer. Still thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

As Prise stated, the easiest solution would be to use [DriveDetector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx) or similar.
Here is an example:

```
    public void InitDriveDetector()
    {
        this.dd = new DriveDetector(); // create the drive detector
        // add new event handlers
        dd.DeviceArrived += new DriveDetectorEventHandler(dd_DeviceArrived);
        dd.DeviceRemoved += new DriveDetectorEventHandler(dd_DeviceRemoved);
    }

    void dd_DeviceRemoved(object sender, DriveDetectorEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} removed",e.Drive);
        //Will output something like "H:\ removed"
    }

    void dd_DeviceArrived(object sender, DriveDetectorEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} arrived",e.Drive);
        //Will output something like "H:\ removed"
    }
```